# How do I get the touchscreen on an HP L5006tm working?

Tags: 12.04, hp, input-devices, touchscreen

I just got an HP L5006tm given to me (it was going to the dumpster -- wtf?) and I'd like to use it with my ubuntu desktop. I've looked at some pages of the wiki but I'm not sure where to start to get the touchscreen working. It's currently acting as a screen, but the touch part isn't working. Any advice?

Comment: What is the ID you get with lsusb?

Comment: @int_ua, it doesn't show up with `lsusb`. Would it even be there if it is a monitor?

Comment: Does it have any other connector besides the video? How does the touchscreen connects to the PC?

Comment: I didn't have it plugged in -_- (first time dealing with a touchscreen, completely wasn't thinking). `lsusb` displays `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e7:0020 Elo TouchSystems Touchscreen Interface (2700)`

Answer (score 1):

I simply installed the `xserver-xorg-input-elographics` package from the repos. Once that was installed my screen magically began to work.